# Масштабирование текста

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Добрый день.
Во время верстки веб-страницы у меня возникла проблема.
На странице имеется элемент `span` содержащий некоторый текст и стоящий рядом `img`.
Мне необходимо сделать буквы равными по высоте картинке.
Я попробовал явно указать в css размеры этих элементов  в виде

```
img {max-height: 100px;}
span {font-size: 100px}
```

Однако, фактическая высота самих букв получается меньше 100px.  Я думаю, я смогу подогнать высоту букв под размер картинки, играясь с `font-size`, но есть ли другой способ?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Вряд ли. http://htmlbook.ru/files/images/css/css_font-size_1.png

Comment: Полезная схема. Кажется, она полностью отвечает на вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nvLmcnqs/ - так?

```
img {
  height: 1ex;
}
```

Comment: Интересное решение для задания высоты, равной иксу. Так, по-моему, нагляднее: http://jsfiddle.net/9424uzon/2/

Comment: Очень интересное простое решение, и оно полностью решает задачу.
Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, всё придётся делать "на глаз", могу посоветтовать для span задать `line-height: 100px;`, а вот font-size уже подгонять. Еще много зависит от шрифта.
Обычно соотношение примерно такое:

- заглавная буква - 2/3 от размера шрифта
- прописная буква - 1/2 от размера шрифта

Comment: И зачем знать единицы измерения?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/nvLmcnqs/4/ чуток исправил - прикрепил фото и добавил стилей к фото и тексту